# can anyone point to me what im doing wrong with my login form in VB (visual studio 2010, mdb)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, authentication, ms-access-2007, oledb

im not sure why or where the problem is anymore since i was already able to login using this code a while ago.

so here, im just trying to create a login form, im going to put encryption for the password later, but right now i just cant seem to connect to my ms2003-2007mdb file, its always ends up showing my mssge unable to connect, i used the same code a while ago and when tried to combine my password encryption it went haywire, now that ive restored my original log in form it just doesnt work
so this is what i have

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class FormLogin

```
Public Sub login()
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = ..\debug\admin.mdb"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT uname, pword FROM users where username=admin", con)
    Dim uname As String = uname_txtfield.Text
    Dim pword As String = pword_txtfield.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uname", uname)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pword", pword)
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If read.HasRows Then
            read.Read()
            If uname = read.Item("uname").ToString And pword = read.Item("pword") Then
                FormChckin.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            ElseIf uname = "Admin" And String.IsNullOrEmpty(pword) Then
                Uinfo_lbl.Text = "The Default Username is Admin, password is password"
            ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(uname) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(pword) Then
                MsgBox("Enter Username & Password, then try again")
            Else
                MsgBox("Username and password does not match")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Unable to login")
        End If
        read.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Login_btn.Click
    login()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try dropping this code? I do not think you need this if you are accessing a local database file unless you have a username and password on the file. And if that is the case you can add it in the connection string
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uname", uname)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pword", pword)
Let me know if removing those lines help. im used to connecting to databases in C#, i havent used VB is a minute but thought this might help. good luck!

Comment: it shows this error when i remove that
system.invalidOperationException: No data exists for the row/column.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.DoValueCheck(Int32 ordinal) 
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetValueCheck(Int32 ordinal) 
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at WindowsApplcation8FormLogin.login() in ~~directory~~ line 17
where line 17 is
If uname = read.Item("uname").ToString And pword = read.Item("pword") Then

Comment: OK so i just dropped the code started from scratch btw, because vs just wants to be differently hard, it was supposed to be the only problem, then it crashed

Comment: Thats always a good way to do it some times just gutting out infected areas makes it clear how to better write it the next time. While i know people claim do it only once, often times when i revisit my code after a couple weeks i think, Woah what did i do at 3Am  weeks ago and to go rewrite the night away. Good Luck getting everything to work.

Comment: Oh my i didnt look closely enough, another error when saying username=admin should have been 'Admin' but idk if that was your problem considering your post.